# mysql left outer join ranking

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to rank with the left outer join

My sql is :

```
SET @rank=0;

SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, h.name, COUNT(v.hId) AS votes
  FROM users h LEFT OUTER JOIN users_votes v ON h.id = v.hId GROUP BY h.id
 ORDER BY rank ASC
;
```

The right thing would be to return like this

```
rank |  name    |   votes

1   Luck        4   
2   Marc        3
3   Santos      2
4   Matheus     0
```

But it's returning the wrong way:

```
rank |  name    |   votes

1   Santos      2   
2   Marc        3
3   Luck        4
4   Matheus     0
```

Comment: Your question lacks details.

Answer (score 0):

You are ordering in `ASC` way, change it to `DESC`. Like this:

```
SET @rank=0;

SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, h.name, COUNT(v.hId) AS votes
  FROM users h LEFT OUTER JOIN users_votes v ON h.id = v.hId GROUP BY h.id
 ORDER BY rank DESC
;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you should use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as rank,
       h.name, COUNT(*) AS votes
FROM users h LEFT OUTER JOIN
     users_votes v
     ON h.id = v.hId
GROUP BY h.id
ORDER BY rank ASC;
```

Variables are deprecated in 8+.

In earlier version, you can use variables, but they tend not to respect `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY`.  So, with those constructs, you need a subquery:

```
SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) as rank, hv.*
FROM (SELECT h.name, COUNT(*) AS votes
      FROM users h LEFT OUTER JOIN
           users_votes v
           ON h.id = v.hId
      GROUP BY h.id
      ORDER BY rank ASC
     ) hv CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0) params;
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't works, the rank number is wrong. I want to sort by votes and rank the most voted